# Using services from Node

Tags: ros, gazebo, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi all,
I need to call a service from node. I was trying to find something to write in .cpp file for calling the service.

I found something in the [API](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1service.html#33d9fb0f32ff8bbac4db4188d657715d), but i don't understand how to use it.

I have to call the service "gazebo/apply_body_wrench" described in [Gazebo Tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/Gazebo_ROS_API#Apply_Wrenches_to_Links).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12647/using-services-from-node/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingServiceClient(c%2B%2B)

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3